# Nested ajax form within a ruby form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Thanks in advance for whoever tries to resolve my issue.
I am new to rails so please help, I have

```
rails g scaffold City name:string
rails g scaffold Area name:string city:references
rails g scaffold User name:string brief:text
rails g migration CreateAreasUsers id:false area:references user:references

rake db:migrate
```

`CreateAreasUsers` is a table join bw area and user

`City` and `Areas` are pre-populated

## Two issues

1) How to add functionality in user form so that :areas_users (join table) is also updated.

2) City and Area are separate models so how can I change select tag for city with select tag for area (however area depends on city)
like:

```
<div id="foo">
<select>
 <% @cities.each do |city|%>
  <option value="<%=city.id%>"> <%=city.name%> </option>
 <%end%>
<select/>
```

```
 <div id="bar">
    <select>
     <% @areas.each do |area|%>
      <option value="<%=area.id%>"> <%=area.name%> </option>
     <%end%>
    <select/>
    </div>
```

div foo should be interchanged with div bar within the new user form
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so since you're a Rails newbie, I'll explain what you need to know.

---

**Association**

Firstly, you're dealing with [**ActiveRecord associations**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). I guess you have some idea as to how they work, as you've asked pertinent questions.

If you need to know the specifics, you've been making a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationship:

[image]

This does not require any extra models - it gives you the ability to invoke associated data directly with the join table itself.

--

To answer your first question:

> How to add functionality in user form so that `:areas_users` (join
>   table) is also updated.

The answer is to pass the appropriate data through your `habtm` association:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :areas
end

#app/models/area.rb
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This allows you to reference `@user.areas` and `@area.users` respectively, including forms:

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.select :areas, Area.all, multiple: true %>
<% end %>
```

*Normally* you'd use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for this type of functionality. This is a slightly different matter which I'd have to explain with another post.

You can then alter your `@user` object with the following:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @user = User.new user_params
   end

   private 

   def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:user, :params, :areas)
   end
end
```

---

For your second question:

> City and Area are separate models so how can I change select tag for
>   city with select tag for area (however area depends on city) like

This is a little more involved.

First of all, you need to have your associations set up correctly. I recommended the above based on what you posted; I am not a mind reader, so if it's wrong, it's because you didn't explain yourself properly.

The bottom line is that your `City` and `Area` models need to have the following associations:

```
#app/models/city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :area
end 

#app/models/area.rb
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cities
end
```

This means that you'll be able to call `@city.area` and `@area.cities`. As such, you'll be able to load a form as follows:

What you need to do is create a way for the selectbox to pull the associated values from your server. Whilst there is likely a `gem` or simpler way to do this, I'll just write it for you whilst I'm in the mood:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :areas do
    get ":id/cities", to: "areas#show" # -> we'll be using the 'show' action
end 

#app/controllers/areas_controller.rb
class AreasController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @area = Area.find params[:id]
       respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json { render json: @area.cities }
       end
    end
end
```

This gives us a hook with which we can use Ajax to pull the relevant cities when an area is selected:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("select.areas").on("change", function(){
   id = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
      url: id + "/cities"
      success: function(data) {
         cities = JSON.Parse(data);
         $('select.cities').find('option').remove();
         $.each(cities, function(index, item) {
            $("select#cities").append( // Append an object to the inside of the select box
            $("<option></option>") // Yes you can do this.
               .text(item.description)
               .val(item.id)
            );
        });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Million thanks for answer it was a great help.. but I am still stuck in same situation (perhaps I framed My question wrong)  Associations Migrations is fine the  issue is my areas_users table is not updated with new user form how to add this functionality. Plus the select tag for city and area should change within new user form so that I can use that area to update my areas_users table+create a new user... and I am failing to do so. U answer was a great help I learned 1 new thing .. and ya thanks again